# Write a huge number of ages to files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have an array `A` of size 200. A[i] = 1,000,000,000 means I need to write to file(s) 1 billion entries of value `i`. For example, A = [2, 3, 1, ...], the output file(s) should be like this

```
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
...
```

Given such array A, how can I output to files (`part-r-00000`, `part-r-00001`, `part-r-00002`, etc.)  using Spark. I am using Spark 2.0.1 with Scala.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to write in each file? Is part-r-00000 for A[0] filled with 0s, part-r-00001 for A[1] filled with 1s, and so on, up to part-r-00199 for A[199] filled with 199s?

Comment: No, I want to let Spark handle auto split (a new file) when first file cannot store any more ages.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason of expanding the data when written to disk. Why would you need `[2,3,1] = (0,0,1,1,1,2)` instead of `[2,3,1] = [(0,2), (1,3),(2,1)]` ??

Comment: @LuongBaLinh I think you're going in the wrong direction. This step is going to explode data volumes without adding any value. I would reconsider the approach.

Comment: See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach this with the automatic *saveAsTextFile()* method, which does what you want by default, splitting into different files, one file per RDD.

[Save the RDD to files](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter3/save_the_rdd_to_files.html)

The maximum size of the files depends on the filesystem used, so although not 100%, I doubt there's an automatic way of doing it.

Based on the code from that example, I would calculate NUM_PARTITIONS before calling *.repartition()* based on the number of entries and what you know of the filesystem if you can get that info from system calls, or you want to default to some values.

Comment: The problem is that I only have the array A, not the inputFile.

Comment: I linked to that example for the output bit (from RDDs to files), ignore the inputFile part; it should be straight forward to map the A array to RDDs.

Comment: Given A = [2, 3, 1, ...], how can I map to (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ...)? The output map will be too large to be stored in memory.

Comment: That's not a problem, your distributed spark cluster will take care of that, that's transparent to your code. When the RDDs don't fit in memory (that's the combined RAM of your cluster), it will split to disk or even be recomputed (you can configure that).

Comment: Sorry, still do not understand. Would you mind to write a few lines of code to "map the A array to RDDs". Thanks.

Comment: There are several ways of doing it and you are going to have to choose based on performance, partition sizes, and the fact that you want the output in order, which means that the parallelisation might not give you that much of an advantage. You can try something like sc.parallelize(A.zipWithIndex).map(n => for(i <- 0 until n._1) yield (n._2)) to get an idea of how you can see an indexed sequence like the one you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126456/discussion-between-luong-ba-linh-and-palako).